# print don't color string on terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, python-3.6

When I try to apply a command to color a string, on the visual studio code's terminal it comes out with '⬅️[33m' in front of it instead, how can I fix this?

Code:

[image: the code]

Terminal output:

[image: terminal]

i'm using the newest v.s. code version and python 3.6

Comment: You'd need to run your program in a terminal that supports ansi colour codes. There is an [ANSI colors extension for visual studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iliazeus.vscode-ansi) but I don't know if it does what you want.